# Wave with 3 different wavelengths

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, waves

Can a 3D wave have 3 different wavelengths ? Is there any example of such a wave ? I can't imagine such a wave because then 3 different frequencies must exist.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a simple sinusoidal 3D plane wave, $A\sin(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}-\omega t)$. Along the $x$-direction, the wavelength is $2\pi/k_x$, and similarly for the $y$ and $z$ directions. But along the direction of propagation of the wave, which is $\hat{k}$, the wavelength is $2\pi/|\vec{k}|$; this is what is considered *the* wavelength.

Note that this wave does *not* have three frequencies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why some textbooks refer to the wave function as Asin(ωt-kx) and not like the above function ?

Comment: Because if you have only one wave, it is simpler to choose a coordinate system in which the wave is propagating along one of the coordinate directions.

Comment: Sorry i meant why the function isn't Asin(ωt-kr) ? Why the argument of the function must be this way ?

Comment: They are equivalent. They just differ in phase by 180 degrees.